# Google analytics ip anonymisation breaks code

Tags: google-analytics

I have addded the code

```
ga('set', 'anonymizeIp', true);
```

to the Google Analytics tracking code, but this stops the tracking code from working. Looking in the console, I get the following error:

```
 (index):363 Uncaught TypeError: ga is not a function
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I was using an old version of the tracking code, which initialises ga as follows:

```
var ga = document.createElement('script');
```

so, ga is just a variable, hence the error that it is not a function.  If you replace the old code with the new code, it has

```
(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
```

and ga is a function, so

```
ga('set', 'anonymizeIp', true);
```

does not trigger an exception.